# Unable to create Maven project using eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am new to Maven set up & facing challenges while setting it up.When eclipse is running configuration to set up Maven, it throws an error as below:

`CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out`

I am absolutely able to download resources of `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/` manually and don't see to understand connect timed error. I've cleaned **.m2** folder & started fresh maven project configuration & no luck. In addition, I don't see setting.xml in .m2 folder. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your eclipse connections are setup through Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections,

also check Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings. If there is a path specified such as 'C:\Users\user.m2\settings.xml' make sure it exists and fill it in appropriately, try following [This Link](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added all external jars from 'Project->Properties->Java build path->libraries'. 
2) Then from 'order and export tab->need to export all jar files'.
3) Then make sure you have set all dependencies from 'pom.xml' file.

**Dependencies**

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
```

Make sure its latest source and target version.